# Static hedge for up-and-out Digital Call

Tags: options, hedging

I am trying to come up with a static hedge for a Digital Call with strike K that knocks out when price > barrier H. I know it will involve non-knockout digital calls with strike K and strike H but I am not sure in what proportion and what other digitals I will need to include in the hedge.

Appreciate any advice and suggestions. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\mathbb{1}_{S_T > K, \max_{[0,T]} S_t < H} &\approx \frac{(S_T - (K-\varepsilon))^+ - (S_T - (K+\varepsilon))^+}{2 \varepsilon} \mathbb{1}_{\max_{[0,T]} S_t < H} \\
&= \frac{(S_T - (K-\varepsilon))^+\mathbb{1}_{\max_{[0,T]} S_t < H}  - (S_T - (K+\varepsilon))^+\mathbb{1}_{\max_{[0,T]} S_t < H} }{2 \varepsilon} 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
so you can start with the static hedge of standard knock out calls $(S_T - (K-\varepsilon))^+\mathbb{1}_{\max_{[0,T]} S_t < H}$ and $(S_T - (K+\varepsilon))^+\mathbb{1}_{\max_{[0,T]} S_t < H}$ if you're already familiar with that.